Specify default attribute value in Python class
I would like to construct a class where an initial attribute depends on the result of an external function and gives a default value otherwise. E.g., Puzzle has a default score of the length of the string used to initialize it, but if no string is provided, its score is -1.
class Puzzle:
    def __init__(self, string):
        self.score = len(string) || -1

This obviously doesn't work as no such syntax is allowed.
One way to do this is with try-except:
class Puzzle:
    def __init__(self, string):
        self.score = -1    # probably redundant

        try:
            self.score = len(string)
        except:
            self.score = -1    # could this be pass instead?

Is there a more concise way to do it?

I'd check if any genAI knows this because it feels like something I should remember.... but I'd like to give some folks a chance to answer an easy question.

I'll try this - self.score = len(string) is a simplified version of what I need, but I hope the basic logic works. Also, I just found out that || is a relic of my C-like training, I should have used or :P

indeed, though similarly to C-land, watch out with or as it cares if something is "Falsey", so 0 or "" will find the second value! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39983695/what-is-truthy-and-falsy-how-is-it-different-from-true-and-false

Use a default such as None:
class Puzzle:
    def __init__(self, string=None):
        if string is None:
            self.score == -1
        else
            self.score = len(string)


To fix the first error, I should have just used or as mentioned in my comment.
class Puzzle:
    def __init__(self, string) :
        self.score = len(string) or -1

Full disclosure: I got this from ChatGPT, but I also tested it in my own Python terminal before pasting it here.
But @ti7 also noted that or accepts "Falsey" values, so it is good to be careful there.
